# Magento 2 After upgrade 2.1.7 to 2.2.7 Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed error throw

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

After upgrade magento2.1.7 to magento 2.2.7 following error show.How to solve it .

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
>   Line: 785

Following is a screen shoot:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the layout file causing that error?

Comment: please try to https://github.com/outeredge/magento-structured-data-module/commit/41ea6ca81a2d8499b954498bce09b7be9d80dc2a